# how to get multiple values from two table in php laravel in a table?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have two Tables namly AllotmentApps and Groups.
I want to extract values from these two tables as shown in Final Table.

I've achieved my goal about 70%. The only problem that I'm facing to show the Group CGPA. In Each Group, The Group CGPA must be show that. belongs to the same Group ID. For example if **GrpID 1**  have value **3.5** , then in the final table is must show only in the group where GrpId is 1.
But in my case it is not according to the GrpID.

[Final Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHa2A.png)

Below is the code of my Controller:

```
  public function View_GroupStudent()
{
    $allot_apps = AllotmentApps::join('Groups','Groups.id','AllotmentApps.id')->orderBy('grpID')->get()->groupBy(
      function($item) { 
        return $item->grpID;
    }
  );
      //dd([$allot_apps->name]);
    return view('deny', compact('allot_apps'));
}
```

Here is the code for view.blade.php

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
@foreach ($allot_apps as $GID => $member_list)

    <tr>
        <th colspan="3" 
            style="background-color: #F7F7F7 ; text-align: center;">
             Grp Id:{{ $GID }}    ,   Members:  {{ $member_list->count() }}

    <tr style="background-color: #F7F7F7 ;"  >
        <th > Name</th>
        <th> Student CGPA</th>
        <th > Group CGPA</th>
    </tr>
         </th>
    </tr>
   
    
    @foreach ($member_list as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $user->sname }}</td>
            <td>{{ $user->cgpa }}</td>
            <td >{{ $user->name}}</td>
           <!--  <td>{{ $user->grpID }}</td> -->
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You Join is not correct. Please read the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins).

```php
AllotmentApps::join('Groups','Groups.id','AllotmentApps.id')
```

You ask for joining AllotmentApps with Groups. Thats fine. But then you said that both primary keys have to be the same. So you join for example Groups.id = 1 with AllotmentApps.id = 1

I assume that you want, to compare foreign and primary key:

```php
AllotmentApps::join('Groups','Groups.id','AllotmentApps.group_id')
```

(Or vice versa. I do not know your database model)

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function View_GroupStudent()
{
    $allot_apps = AllotmentApps::join('Groups','Groups.id','AllotmentApps.grpID')->orderBy('grpID')->get()->groupBy(
      function($item) { 
        return $item->grpID;
    }
  );
     // dd([$allot_apps]);
    return view('deny', compact('allot_apps'));
}
```

it was `AllotmentApps.grpID` instead `AllotmentApps.id`